# How to inject variable inside template_from_string in twig?

Tags: twig

I want to use template variable (as string) inside a loop.

```
{# Define my template #}
{% set my_template %}
    <span>{{ job.title }}</span>
    ...
{% endset %}

{# Using the template inside a loop #}
{% for job in jobs %}
    {{ include(template_from_string(my_template), { 'job', job }) }}
{% endfor %}
```

I expect it shows the template content with the corresponding value for "job", but there is an error: "Variable job is not defined"

Comment: Your code should work as is. As seen [here](https://www.darkbee.be/web/template.php). Also if the variable caries the same name, you don't need the extra argument (see test). Make sure you are reading the correct error.

Comment: It doesn't work, I have already tried this. This does not work, The `job` variable is not defined as the error said

Comment: Of course it *does* work, otherwise the demo I've linked to would not execute...

Comment: I've just realized that you used inline `set`, I've just tried it and it works, but what I use is `set` block (for more content). Thank you

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry did not extend on that. To problem is when you use `set` like that, the twig inside the `set`, will already be executed in front. But i'm guessing your dynamic templates will be loaded from a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use macro 
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html

```
{% macro my_template(job) %}
    <span>{{ job.title }}</span>
    ...
{% endset %}

{# Using the template inside a loop #}
{% for job in jobs %}
    {{ include(template_from_string(_self.my_template(job)), { 'job', job }) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: something like this, didn’t check, but macro will solve your problem exactly

Comment: It works for me, thank you. just adjust your correction and I will validate it. Here we don't need `include` and `template_from_string` anymore

Answer (score 1):

I think your `include` call has a mistake in passing the parameters. You are providing a regular array instead of the hash (using the comma instead of the colon):

```
{{ include(template_from_string(_self.my_template(job)), { 'job': job }) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the `verbatim` tag.
This stops twig parsing the variables, and force string, so we can we run as twig template later on.

**Without** `verbatim`:

```twig
{# Define my template #}
{% set jobs = ['11', '22'] %}
{% set job = 'outside' %}

{% set my_template %}
  <span>{{ job }}</span>
{% endset %}

{# Using the template inside a loop #}
{% for job in jobs %}
  {{ include(template_from_string(my_template), { 'job': job }) }}
{% endfor %
```

Output: `outside outside` (wrong)

**With** `verbatim`:

```twig
{# Define my template #}
{% set jobs = ['11', '22'] %}
{% set job = 'outside' %}

{% set my_template %}
  {% verbatim  %}
    <span>{{ job }}</span>
  {% endverbatim %}
{% endset %}

{# Using the template inside a loop #}
{% for job in jobs %}
  {{ include(template_from_string(my_template), { 'job': job }) }}
{% endfor %
```

Output: `11 22` (correct)

**Bonus** - Drupal - no template_from_string() **With** `verbatim`:

```twig
{# Define my template #}
{% set jobs = ['11', '22'] %}
{% set job = 'outside' %}

{% set my_template %}
  {% verbatim  %}
    <span>{{ job }}</span>
  {% endverbatim %}
{% endset %}

{# Using the template inside a loop #}
{% for job in jobs %}
  {{ {'#type': 'inline_template', '#template': my_template, '#context': {'job': job} } }}
{% endfor %
```

Output: `11 22` (correct)